# How to establish the identity

Tags: trigonometry

How do I establish the identity in this problem? Struggling with this one at the moment. 
$$\frac{\sin\theta\cos\theta}{\cos^2\theta-\sin^2\theta}=\frac{\tan\theta}{1-\tan^2\theta}$$

Comment: Hello ex101, I edited your post to bemore clear. Is this what you meant to say?

Comment: @VladimirLenin Yes, thank you!

Comment: If you multiply the numerators by $2$, you'll have three expressions that *might* be familiar to you: the left-hand numerator, the left-hand denominator, and the entire right-hand side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have
$$\frac{\tan \theta}{1-\tan^2 \theta}=\frac{\frac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}}{1-\frac{\sin^2\theta}{\cos^2\theta}}=\frac{\frac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}}{\frac{\cos^2\theta}{\cos^2\theta}-\frac{\sin^2\theta}{\cos^2\theta}}=\frac{\frac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}}{\frac{\cos^2\theta-\sin^2\theta}{\cos^2\theta}}=\frac{\sin\theta(\cos^2\theta)}{\cos\theta(\cos^2\theta-\sin^2\theta)}=\frac{\sin\theta\cos\theta}{\cos^2\theta-\sin^2\theta}$$

Comment: Can you explain what you did in step 4: sinθ(cos2θ)/cosθ(cos2θ-sin2θ) to get the solution?

Comment: Notice that $\frac{\cos^2\theta}{\cos\theta}=\cos\theta.$

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 3):

$\bf hint: $ divide the top and bottom of $$\frac{\sin t\cos t}{\cos^2 t- \sin^2 t } $$ by $\cos^2 t.$ now use the fact $\tan t = \frac{\sin t}{\cos t}.$

Comment: What if $t$ is such that $\cos^2 t = 0$?

Comment: @DilipSarwate, if $\cos^2 t = 0,$ then then rhs is undefined for one thing.

Comment: Yes, but the other proofs, as well as the OP's question "establish the _identity"_ (emphasis added), seem to suggest that the result holds for all $t$ whereas you seem to be saying that it holds only when $t$ is not an odd multiple of $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: @DilipSarwate,   it is enough to establish this identity on any open interval.

Answer (score 0):

Put $\tan = \frac{\sin}{\cos}$
and simplify.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{\sin\theta\cos\theta}{\cos^2\theta-\sin^2\theta}=\frac{\tan\theta}{1-\tan^2\theta}$$
$$\implies \frac{2\sin\theta\cos\theta}{\cos^2\theta-\sin^2\theta}=\frac{2\tan\theta}{1-\tan^2\theta}$$
Now using $\sin 2\theta=2\sin\theta\cos\theta$ and $\cos 2\theta=\cos^2\theta-\sin^2\theta$
$$\frac{\sin 2\theta}{\cos 2\theta}=\tan 2\theta$$
Now using $\tan 2\theta=\frac{2\tan \theta}{1-\tan^2\theta}$ we get
$$\tan 2\theta=\frac{2\tan \theta}{1-\tan^2\theta}$$
Which is what we wanted to prove.